# assembler - How to check, if a specific key is being pressed

Tags: assembly

I`m doing a bit of programming in the assembly language. I have got a question. How can I check if a key is being pressed, *e.g.* if I am pressing the <kbd>F8</kbd> key, jump to reboot.

Comment: Which assembly are you using ?

Comment: Whats the operating system you are using?

Comment: Oh, sorry I am creating a simple bootloader. I am using assembler. (NASM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me (assuming x86 real mode):

```
[org 0x100]
[bits 16]

mov dx,prompt
mov ah,9
int 21h

wait_for_f8:
  mov ah,0
  int 16h       ; Get keystroke

  cmp ah,42h    ; 42h == scancode for F8
  jne wait_for_f8

mov dx,exit_msg
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov ax,4c00h
int 21h

prompt: db 'Please press F8..$'
exit_msg: db 13,10,'F8 pressed',13,10,'$'
```

The DOS interrupts (`int 21h`) are only there to give some feedback to the user. In a boot loader you wouldn't need those (if you need text output in your boot loader you could use `int 10h` instead, or write directly to video memory).

Comment: Thanks, it really helped! But, how can I check for input from two keys at the same time, ex if F8 is pressed, jump to foo, and if F9 is pressed, jump to bar?

Comment: @PeterNicholson: Something like this should do: `cmp ah,something / je foo / cmp ah,something_else / je bar / jmp wait_for_keys`